# Problem of aligning three equations horizontally by using multicols

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, multicol

I have trouble to align three equations horizontally by using multicols. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
   \begin{equation}
      f(x)=tanh(x)
   \end{equation}
   \begin{equation}
      \sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}
   \end{equation}
   \begin{equation}
       f(x) = 
           \begin{cases} 
               0 & \text{for}\ x < 0 \\
               x & \text{for}\ x \ge 0
           \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you using `multicols` only to get the three equations next to each other? If so, there are alternative ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `multicols`, use 3 `minipage`s.

Margin frame shown for verification.  Don't forget `\noindent` and also no spaces between end of one `minipage` and beginning of next.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.333\linewidth}
   \begin{equation}
      f(x)=\tanh(x)
   \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.333\linewidth}
   \begin{equation}
      \sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}
   \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.333\linewidth}
   \begin{equation}
       f(x) = 
           \begin{cases} 
               0 & \text{for}\ x < 0 \\
               x & \text{for}\ x \ge 0
           \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternatives to [Steven B. Segletes' nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459400/121799). In particular, the second one adjusts the widths of the equations automatically, i.e. you do not have to pay with hardcoded distances if the equations have (very) different widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent
   \begin{equation}
\vphantom{f(x) = 
           \begin{cases} 
               0 & \text{for}\ x < 0 \\
               x & \text{for}\ x \ge 0
           \end{cases}}         
      f(x)=\tanh(x)
   \end{equation}
\columnbreak
   \begin{equation}
\vphantom{f(x) = 
           \begin{cases} 
               0 & \text{for}\ x < 0 \\
               x & \text{for}\ x \ge 0
           \end{cases}}         
      \sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}
   \end{equation}
\columnbreak
   \begin{equation}
       f(x) = 
           \begin{cases} 
               0 & \text{for}\ x < 0 \\
               x & \text{for}\ x \ge 0
           \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\tanh(x) & &\stepcounter{equation}(\theequation) &
      \sigma(x) &= \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} & & \stepcounter{equation}(\theequation)&
       f(x) &= 
           \begin{cases} 
               0 & \text{for}\ x < 0 \\
               x & \text{for}\ x \ge 0
           \end{cases} &
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]